# LiDAR Mapping Methods for a straight section of featureless environment (straight sections of pipe, tunnels etc)

Tags: slam, mapping, lidar, point-cloud

Are there lidar mapping methods(algorithms/software packages) available that can be used to map featureless environment like straight sections of pipes? (It could use imu/wheel encoders to estimate the odometry). I am trying to generate a 3d point cloud model of a pipe.